# can we use table name instead java class name in select or update queries in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

In hibernate we use class names generally in select and update queries.My question  is it possible to direct give table name (if user wants in some scenario).For example :- in below queries i have table name as ContentModification.

```
select from ContentModification as cm where cm.XWC_NAME=:spaceName
update ContentModification set  lastname="miles"
```

Another question can we use query object in hibernate to insert the data(like insert into ..). Every where i just see the examples of update ans select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Create native query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/hem/en-US/html/query_native.html#d0e4753)

But why bother with hibernate in the first place then ?

Comment: This might be the best way... But I don't understand the usage of Hibernate for this purpose. Since Hibernate is not a controller for database querying - It's an ORM Container to manage entities. So why bother with Table names and database related jargon with Hibernate ?

Comment: I agree hibernate does not have role here. But its is already used in project, I just want to to know can we mention table name or not.Its a long story behind this.